# Excel opens a csv correctly, but cannot import it as text

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I am trying to create an excel dashboard of sorts. I need to import an often changing csv file into excel 2013. The file is by default encoded in UTF-8. I cannot change this.

As many, many questions on this site and others show, this is difficult. Specifically, multiline cells break the "From Text" import. I have tried many combinations of delimiters and settings. Most solutions involve manually editing the  file to effectively change the encoding.

The thing is, it works correctly if I just double click on the csv file from the windows browser. Therefore, there must be some set of settings which work! Excel is capable of it. Reviewing my control panel language settings, I have the default settings for delimiters ("comma").

Answer (score 1):

Use Power Query for loading the data. When the data source has been changed you only need to refresh the query. Power Query is [available](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/power-query-overview-and-learning-ed614c81-4b00-4291-bd3a-55d80767f81d) as a download for Excel 2013.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Ben. This is harder than it ought to be given corporate software installation rules. It's hard to believe this is the only way to do it, even if it is definitely the easiest.